# How can I replace a string?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a string (this string comes from the database i.e. a dynamic string) that contains two `<a>` tags. E.g.:

```
$str = '<a href="http://www.google.com" key1="value1">Any string</a>
       <a key1="value1" href="http://www.google.com">Any string</a>';
```

How can I add a separate `onclick` attribute to the `<a>`  tags in that string, i.e first `<a>` tag `onclick="test1()"`, the next `<a>` tag `onclick="test2()"` etc., by using PHP `preg_replace` or another method?

Comment: `php` is a much better tag than `meta`, don't you think? ;)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: Does it have to pure php, or do you allow for javascript solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = str_replace(' href="',' onclick="test(this)" href="',$str);
```

That's significantly faster than `preg_replace` since it doesn't have to match a pattern.
This of course, depends on the way you're using it.

Comment: Nice one, but not really what @Royal wants. You have the same onclick handler for every `<a>` instead of `test1(), test2(),...`

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** : *This solution will only work with your current string pattern (which seems to be a collection of links)*

**NOTE 2** : You could also use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) for this

To finally answer your question

```
$str =  str_ireplace ('<a ', '<a onclick="doSomething(this)"', $str);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

**EDIT**

@Eldros pointed out that the methods need to be different for each link.

In that I would definitely suggest you take care of it on the client side. But if you *must* do this with PHP, you could use a library like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for DOM parsing.
**Note that this does *not* use DOM manipulation but rather string parsing.** This may or may not matter to you.

This is an example from the documentation showing how to modify your string. See the documentation for full usage : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

```
// Create DOM from string
$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');
$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';
$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';
echo $html; // Output: <div id="hello">foo</div><div id="world" class="bar">World</div>
```

In your case, you'd just load your string with `str_get_html` and loop through it modifying your link one by one.

Comment: @JohnP Consider matching `<a ` instead of just `<a` in order to *not* replace the first part of a `<abbr>` tag. (Note: This may not be an issue, depending on the input.)

Comment: @JohnP doesn't it gives all the anchors the same function for the onclick event?

Comment: @Eldros didn't notice that. Edited my answer with an alternative. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @Eldros aaaand just noticed that you pointed to the exact same library! Hope you don't mind! I've actually used it and can confirm that he can do what he needs with this

Comment: @JohnP No problem. In the end, we came out with the same solution. :) I have one question though: On the php site, I've looked into the functions `str_ireplace`, that you use, and `str_replace`, that @Christian use, and I don't see why I should use one instead of the other in this case. Is there any advantages I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Eldros the difference is in what it matches. The `i` in `str_ireplace` stands for `case insensitive`. So mine will match `<A ` as well as `<a ` Best used if you don't know the case of the string. I prefer using case insensitive methods because you never know what will come through :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use this library, but with the help of [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), you could use this code to try and add the functions:

```
//array containing your functions names
$functions = array(test1, test2);

//Parse the string to get the HTML DOM
$html = str_get_html($str);

//Retrieve the array of anchors
$links = $html->find('a');

//Loop through the anchors and add the onclick events
for($i=0;$i<count($links);$i++){
    $links[$i]->onclick = $functions[$i];
}

//return the html to the string
$html->save();
```

You'll probably have to test it a bit and change it so it could pass into your process.

**EDIT:** To adapt this solution so as to use unobtrusive JavaScript, you could replace `$links[$i]->onclick` by `$links[$i]->id`, and then add an eventHandler with javascript:

```
//Add an event listener that will trigger when the content of the page is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var i;

    //retrieve all the anchors
    var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    //Loop through the anchors
    for(i=0; i<links.length; i++){
        //If the anchor has an id
        if(links[i].id){
            //retrieve the function
            var myFuncName = links[i].id;
            var myFunction = window[myFuncName];
            //add the event listener
            links[i].addEventListener("change", myFunction, false);
        }
    }
}, false);
```

It is important to retrieve the function as it is has been done here, as `links[i].id` is a string, and addEeventListener wouldn't have worked with a string instead of the function. As `window.function` is the same as `window['function']`, this do the conversion perfectly.

As with the PHP code, this could be object to change depending on your environment. For example if all the anchors who needs an `onchange` eventHandler are situated under a `div` tag with id "mylinks", you can change `document.getElementsByTagName("a");` by `document.getElementById("mylinks).getElementsByTagName("a");`.